# Merge two arrays in one, combining the data correspondingly

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Having these two arrays with exactly the same number of items (3) and respectively correspondent data, how can I merge them to one unique array, combining the data like I show in array 3 example

```
// array 1
[ ▼ 3 items
  {
    "email": "john-doe@example.tld"
  },
  {
    "email": "joe-bloggs@example.tld"
  },
  {
    "email": "foo-bar@example.tld"
  }
]

// array 2
[ ▼ 3 items
  {
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe Bloggs"
  },
  {
    "name": "Foo Bar"
  }
]
```

How can I merge them to be like this:

```
// array 3
[ ▼ 3 items
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john-doe@example.tld"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "email": "joe-bloggs@example.tld"
  },
  {
    "name": "Foo Bar",
    "email": "foo-bar@example.tld"
  }
]
```

I am using laravel php. I have tried `array_merge($array1, $array2)` and some laravel's function `$res = $array1->merge($array2);` but I can't get the result I want.

Comment: Can you provide a `var_dump()` of the arrays?  I'm not really sure what that output is that you're giving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your input data looks like so I had to make a few assumptions. The idea is to loop through all emails, take their position in the emails array, and use that position to define what the name would be in the names array.

```
$emails = [
    ["email" => "john-doe@example.tld"], 
    ["email" => "joe-bloggs@example.tld"], 
    ["email" => "foo-bar@example.tld"]
];

$names = [
    ["name" => "John Doe"],
    ["name" => "Joe Bloggs"],
    ["name" => "Foo Bar"]
];

$names_and_emails = [];

foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
    $names_and_emails[] = ["email" => $email['email'], "name" => $names[$key]['name']];
}

var_dump($names_and_emails);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(20) "john-doe@example.tld"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(22) "joe-bloggs@example.tld"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Joe Bloggs"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "foo-bar@example.tld"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Foo Bar"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @hailton thanks for accepting my answer! This is also a good example to understand what's going on behind the scenes when using the array_merge() or Laravel combine() methods.

Answer (score 3):

`array_merge` doesn't combines the elements, it just concatenates the arrays to each other.

You can use `array_map()` to call `array_merge()` on each pair of elements:

```
$result = array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use combine() method of laravel

```
$collection = collect(['name', 'email']);
for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++){
$combined[] = $collection->combine([$array2[$i],$array1[$i]]);
}
$combined->all();
```

or just use collection

```
$collection = collect($array1, $array2);
```